# Edit Sharepoint List Column settings to add color style?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am trying to create a **Choice column** in my Sharepoint list. Using Graph API, this works great: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0

However, it creates the choices with no color. I would like to create these **choices** as labels with colors, as shown in the screenshot below, but I can't find any way to do it either at the creation or when editing the column, in both Graph APIs or Sharepoint CSOM.
[image]

Is this even doable programmatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable , if you click advanced mode. Then you should fill the JSON needed for formatting columns according to your needs.

Please refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this conditional formatting, but I want choice pills instead of conditional formatting as described in the screenshot above.

Comment: It looks like it does work the same way: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292646/help-with-sharepoint-list-columns-make-cell-green-if-value-complete Thanks Edell.

Comment: Yeap, you are right. All you need is the right formula as described in the url you posted. Have a nice one!